# Let $A$ be the set of $2\times 2$ Boolean matrices with $MRN$ if and only if $m_{ij}\le n_{ij}$ for $i,j=1,2$. Is $(A,R)$ a lattice?

Tags: integer-lattices

A Diagraph is said to be a lattice if every pair in lattice has least upper bound (LUB) and Greatest Lower Bound (GLB).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: What is your personal work ? There are 16 such matrices which is a small number (In fact, it could be even boolean vectors of size 4). Have you attempted to make a sketch of this (assumed) lattice ?

Comment: Thank You so much @JoséCarlosSantos .I will take care next time.

Comment: @JeanMarie - I got the 16 such matrices . I don't have any idea about how to proceed ahead.

Comment: Draw an arrow each time you have a relationship between them and see if every pair has a LUB and GLB.

Comment: What should R be ? (R is a relation from M to N but how can it be represented in matrix form) I possibly lack some basics or I haven't understood the question well. Can you help me with it .I got A with 16 2x2 boolean matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the way the different matrices should be arranged is as a 4D hypercube.

See the graphics below where:

$$(a,b,c,d) \ \ \ \ \leftrightarrow \ \ \ \ \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

In fact, you don't need to represent this graphics. You need only say that:

$$\begin{cases}GLB((a,b,c,d),(a',b',c',d'))&=&(\min(a,a'),\min(b,b'),\min(c,c'),\min(d,d'))\\
LUB((a,b,c,d),(a',b',c',d'))&=&(\max(a,a'),\max(b,b'),\max(c,c'),\max(d,d'))\end{cases}$$

for example:

$$LUB((0101),(1000))=(1101)$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer ,It explains all my doubts .Sorry for late reply